# Bash Command Get Data from multiple files and append the file name

Tags: bash, command-line, files

I have in a folder (eg `/tmp`) the following files

```
1.id
2.id
3.id
4.id
```

so on...

In these files, there is one number inside. For example in `1.id` it can be the `1000`, in `2.id` it can be the `2000` etc.

I want an one line bash command to get the value (number) of all these files automatically (`*.id`) but append also the filename of it.

So the output should be:

```
1.id=1000
2.id=2000
```

Comment: How about awk instead of bash? `awk '{$0 = FILENAME"="$0}1' *.id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `grep` in this folder:

```
grep "" *.id
```

Output:

```
1.id:123
2.id:13
3.id:5
4.id:87876
```

**BTW:** I often use this in proc or sysfs filesystems;

```
cd /sys/class/net/eth0
grep "" *
```

This gives you all infos in sysfs about the ethernet interface `eth0`.

Comment: Well that works and it is awesome, however if one file exists eg 1.id it doesnt show the name of it

Comment: @BlackDream Just use `-H` and it will print a filename even if there is only one file.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '{printf "%s=%s\n",FILENAME,$0}' *.id
```

or

```
awk 'OFS="=" {print FILENAME,$0}' *.id
```

---

*Examples*

```
% awk '{printf "%s=%s\n",FILENAME,$0}' *.id
1.id=1000
2.id=2000

% awk 'OFS="=" {print FILENAME,$0}' *.id
1.id=1000
2.id=2000

% awk '{printf "%s:%s\n",FILENAME,$0}' *.id
1.id:1000
2.id:2000
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `bash` one liner :

```
for i in *.id; do echo ""$i"=$(<"$i")"; done
```

Example :

```
$ ls -1
1.id
2.id


$ for i in *.id; do echo ""$i"=$(<"$i")"; done
1.id=10000
2.id=2000
```